# How to get only the number of all files on a drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to get only the number of files on my hard disk drive.

I tried:

```
DIR /S C:\
```

But it lists nearly forever all the files recursively and at the end I get what I want: the number of files.

How do I get only the number of files like 300 000?

Comment: Modern way is the Powershell usage. I would run PS-command even within batch-file: **powershell -nop -c (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_DataFile -Filter 'Drive= ''C:'' ' ).Count**. You shall get different results depending on the user's privilege level: admin, system, users, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List files in bare format and pipe to `find`, which simply counts all lines:

```
dir /s /b /A-D-L c:\* | find /c /v ""
```

lists all files (including hidden and system files) without folders. You can adapt which files to include/exclude. See `dir /?` for details